# How to use URLConnection.getContentLength()

Tags: java, android, url, static-methods, non-static

So I have this rather weird problem with my program. What I try to do is to check the `Content-Length` of a URL and then use this number in a non-static method with an if-else statement connecting other classes. But my problem with this is that while I was researching the internet to somehow solve this problem, there where these static-methods that I could use to get the contentLength and it wouldn't work with non-static. So I tried it but I never really got any results. What I basically tried to do is to call the class with the static-method via non-static-method in another class which, I guess, shouldn't be the problem (or should? I don't really know since I have never worked with static methods before). Then I used this code to determine the contentLength of a random webpage with changing date:

```
    public static void main() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // Adding 1 day
    String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());

    try {
        String urlStr = "http://www.sasintern.de/show_pdf.php?fn=" + output + ".pdf";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();
        if (contentLength < 2000) {
            new NotWorkingActivity();
            System.out.println("unknown content length");
        } else {
            new download2Activity();
            System.out.println("content length: " + contentLength + " bytes");
        }
        InputStream inStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        // now read data
        // ...

        // close connection
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, when the size of the page was determined to be smaller than 2000 bytes, it should show a Toast in another class that the page is not available, but when it was bigger, then it should open up a new class, as you may see in the else-statement. 
But it doesn't work and I think I just messed up with static methods. I'm just not that experienced with them. Sorry for any other mistakes that I might have made. If there is an different solution to my problem which, hopefully, is easier to understand and better to use, I would be very grateful.

Please, I need help on this problem and I hope you understand what I am up to. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using a non-static method like a constructor.

Comment: Too much waffle here. Unclear what you're asking. Please state your actual problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()
> public int getContentLength()
>
> Returns the value of the content-length header field.

Not all resources set the Content-Length header. So, you need to obtain input stream and read all the bytes until the end to count them.

Comment: And `static` and `non-static` have nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP, we're just confused with `static` and `non-static`. They just need the "URL content length". Using `getContentLength()` is not good idea for this kind of task.